# How can I use rmarkdown inline code within a ggtitle

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to get my sample size to appear in my plot title using inline code so that I can avoid the error of forgetting to update (N = 128) each time I use this code chunk. Currently R does not recognize the inline code "(N = `r nrow(df)`)" that I am trying to use in the last line of my code.

```
library(Rmisc) # for summarySE function

# create descriptive stats for bar plot
    df <- subset(mtcars, select = c(mpg, cyl))
    dfc <- summarySE(df, measurevar = "mpg", groupvars = c("cyl"))

# bar plot
ggplot(dfc, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) + # insert variables
      geom_bar(aes(fill=cyl), # essential for bar coloring
               position=position_dodge(),
               stat="identity", colour="black", size=0) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= mpg - se, ymax= mpg + se), 
                    size=.4, width=.1, position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
      ggtitle("(N = `r nrow(df)`)")  ### THIS IS THE LINE I WANT TO WORK ###
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via the [`paste`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) functions as shown:

```
n_value <- paste("( N = ", nrow(dat), ")")
ggtitle(paste0(n_value))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it + give you comma formatted numbers in the event you go into the thousands+.

```
sprintf("( N = %s )", scales::comma(nrow(dat)))

sprintf("( N = %s )", scales::comma(nrow(ggplot2movies::movies)))
## [1] "( N = 58,788 )"
```